# App for updating all social networks with similar information

Tags: social-networks

My friends are on too many different social networks, and often I just want to post the same update to all of them.

As there are different limitations on different networks, the update will have to be slightly tailored for each of the networks, but the basic content can often remain the same.

Is there a tool for that? Is there a self-hosted tool/app/program for that?

I imagine I create a post with text and link/image/video. This can go directly onto Diaspora, Facebook, Google+ and LinkedIn. It can also make a blog-post on Wordpress. By making a short summary of the text, it can go on Twitter.

Comment: Does it have to be self-hosted? That seriously limits the possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

You could use If-This-Then-That, otherwise known as [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/)

This is a web service.  Many social media sites are covered by its range.  You can create recipes such as:

> If I post on Facebook
>   Then Copy the post to Twitter

Create a number of such recipes to copy onto the sites that you want.
They can be adjusted to copy just text or pictures if you wish.